# In ServiceNow, create a record, based on the value of a choice field in a different table

Tags: javascript

I have a situation, where I have 4 different tables A, B, C & D.

- Based on when the choice value of the table A, changes to a specific value of 'Complete', want to check if the details of 2 fields in table A exist in table B also. If they do not, then create a record in table B, using the values of those 2 fields from table A.
- Table C and D are data tables, with table A and table B referencing the fields from table C & D.

So basically:

```
Table C:
    Customer Name
    Customer Address
Table D :
    Service Name
    Service Type
    Service Details
Table A:
    Customer Name - Reference field from table C
    Service Name - Reference field from table D
    Service Status - Choice field (the one which has 'Complete' value)
Table B:
    Customer Name - Reference field from table C
    Service Name - Reference field from table D
    Service Completed - True/False
```

Rules:

- When a service request is received, the table A is manually updated to add a record and the 'Service Status' is 'Started'.
- When the service is completed, the table B is updated (this needs to be automated) and the 'Service Completed' is set to 'true'.
- Sometimes when the service is completed and has an issue, the same record is opened in table A, and the 'Service Completed' in table B is set to 'false'

I need to implement this rule:

> When the service is completed, the table B is updated (this needs to be automated) and the 'Service Completed' is set to 'true'.

The Script Include and Client Scripts that I have written, somehow do not work

***Script Include***

```
var CreateNewRecord = Class.create();
CreateNewRecord.prototype = Object.extendsObject(global.AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
 
    createNewRecord: function() {
        // Retrive the values sent to this script
        var statusSI = this.getParameter('sysparm_statusSI');
        var customerSI = this.getParameter('sysparm_customerSI');
        var serviceSI = this.getParameter('sysparm_serviceSI');
 
        if (statusSI == 'complete') {
            // Select the Table B table
            var grABObj = new GlideRecord('tableB');
            grABObj.addQuery('customer', customerSI);
            grABObj.addQuery('service', serviceSI);
            grABObj.addQuery('active', true);
            grABObj.query();
 
            // Get the next record for the Trader/Broker with the same Name/ID
            if (grABObj.hasNext()) {
                // Do Nothing
            } else {
                var grNewRecord = new GlideRecord('tableB');
                grNewRecord.initialize();
                grNewRecord.setValue('customer', customerSI);
                grNewRecord.setValue('service', serviceSI);
                grNewRecord.setValue('active', false);
                grNewRecord.insert();
            }
        }
    },
    type: 'CreateNewRecord'
});
```

***Client Script:***

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
   if (isLoading || newValue == '') {
        return;
    }
              
    // Check if the current value of the field is "Finalised"
    if (newValue == 'complete') {
        // Create a new record
        var gaEF = new GlideAjax('CreateNewRecord');
        gaEF.addParam('sysparm_name', 'createNewRecord');
 
        gaEF.addParam('sysparm_statusSI', g_form.getValue('status'));
        gaEF.addParam('sysparm_customerSI', g_form.getValue('customer'));
        gaEF.addParam('sysparm_serviceSI', g_form.getValue('service'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Few things 
- What is the XHR response coming? 
- Have you turned on debug mode? when you'll see logs, you might see some error, and this will be related to scope.